# Missing required GCS remote state configuration location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terragrunt

After Google Cloud quota update, I can't run terragrunt/terraform code due to strange error. Same code worked before with other project on same account. After I tried to recreate project (to get new clear project) there was some "Billing Quota" popup and I asked support for changing quota.
I got the following message from support:

**Dear Developer,
We have approved your request for additional quota. Your new quota should take effect within one hour of receiving this message.**

And now (1 day after) terragrunt is not working due to error:
**Missing required GCS remote state configuration location**

Actually what I got:

- service account for pipelines with Project Editor and Service Networking Admin;
- bucket without public access (europe-west3)
- following terragrunt config:

```
remote_state {
    backend = "gcs"

    config = {
        project        = get_env("TF_VAR_project")
        bucket         = "bucket name"
        prefix         = "${path_relative_to_include()}"
    }

    generate = {
        path      = "backend.tf"
        if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
    }
}
```

Also i`m running following pipeline

```
    - terragrunt run-all init
    - terragrunt run-all validate
    - terragrunt run-all plan
    - terragrunt run-all apply --terragrunt-non-interactive -auto-approve
```

and its failing on init with error.'

Project and credentials are correct (also credentials stored in GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS env as json without new lines or whitespaces).

Also tryed to specify "location" in "config" but got error that bucket not found in project.

Does anybody know how to fix or where can be problem?
It worked before I got quota.

Comment: Are you running terragrunt from the correct location?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yep, i got 
**include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}**
which includes file with provider generator. Also after manually adding "location" to generator config i`m getting other error so it 100% correct

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem very randomly.
It resolved for me when I did a new login via the CLI by this command:

> gcloud auth login

I'm not sure if this is always the case, but it seems like my laptop was unauthorized to reach the config files on the GCS.

Comment: In combination with switching to the right `project id`!